# How to replace text in Outlook email body without deleting images

Tags: vba, outlook

In Excel 2016 VBA, I'm automating Outlook to replace text in the body of emails. The part that does the replacement looks like this:

```
Dim oEmail As Object, strEmailSubject As String, strEmailBody As String
Set oEmail = GetActiveOutlookEmail
strEmailBody = TranslateOneEmailElement(oEmail.Body)
If strEmailBody <> oEmail.Body Then oEmail.Body = strEmailBody
```

(I've left out the GetActiveOutlookEmail and TranslateOneEmailElement functions as I don't think they are relevant to the question and would just add a lot of clutter.)

That works fine for the text. However, if the email body had any images, that line deletes them.

How can I replace text line by line so that it leaves images in place?

Comment: Can you post more code or complete code?

Comment: @0m3r, I added more of the code.

Comment: You could use Replace for the specific text strings. If not possible, you could save the images and add them afterwards.

Comment: @niton, I'm already using Replace for the specific text strings, inside the TranslateOneEmailElement function. Yes, I could save the images and add them afterwards, all at the end or the beginning, but I'd like to keep them in the correct positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading and setting the plain text `Body` property wiping out all the formatting, not just images. You need to work with the `HTMLBody` property instead.